# How to replace irregular string prefix using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

So, I have an array of strings that have irregular, non-sequential prefixes (e.g. `1. Some file name; 2. Some file name; 11. Some file name; 10. Some file name; 1. Some file name; 2. Some file name; 2. Some file name;` etc.

How would I go about renaming these sequentially? I'm having a little bit of a mental block, since I'm unclear how replace will affect a variably long first part of the string, while preserving the integrity of the rest of the string (e.g. once the prefix gets to a certain length will it truncate parts of the rest of the string). My second issue is how do consistently identify the changing prefix to get renamed in a for loop? I don't think I can use a fixed substring to grab the prefix, because I will either grab part of or too much of the string. I assume I need to write some sort of function to evaluate and normalize the prefix before using the replace method. I guess in my case I could just grab and replace the first three characters and ignore the "." character, but I'd like to find a more universal and maintainable approach to this.

Here's a snippet that I assume is barking up the wrong tree...

```
if(suffix === "txt"){

 prefix = file.charAt(0);
        console.log(prefix);
        if(!isNaN(prefix)){
            newPre = prefix++;
            newFile = file.replace(newPre, prefix);
            console.log(newFile);
            file1 = path.join(directoryPath, file);
            newFile1 = path.join(directoryPath, newFile);
            fs.rename(file1, newFile1, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log('it worked, mofo!');
            })

        }
```

Edit:

Desired result is the same order of the array re-prefixed as such:

```
[
1. Some file name
2. Some file name
3. Some file name 
etc
]
```

Would be nice to find a result that could deal with multiple character long prefix strings or that would ensure the prefix renaming didn't truncate the rest of the string.

Thanks

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expressions can help you with your problem.

I am assuming the prefix you want to get rid of is the number at the beginning of all your example filenames:

```
1. Some file name
2. Some file name
11. Some file name
10. Some file name
1. Some file name
2. Some file name
2. Some file name
```

In english we would describe the prefix we want to get rid of as: some numbers, followed by a dot, followed by whitespace.

In regular expressions this is written as:

```
   ^      at the beginning of the string
   \d+    match some numbers
   \.     a dot
   \s+    and some whitespace
```

you can try it out online in a [regular expression tester](https://regexr.com/4udhc),
and then incorporate it in your program.

```
newFile = file.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, prefix);
```

To learn more:

- [Introduction to Regular Expressions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

P.S. regular expressions are available in all programming languages.
they are hard to learn because they are so compact, but once you
have understood the basics you can use them in many programming languages.

Comment: thank you, will test this when I haven't had several wines for lunch. This definitely sounds like it will do what I need and deal with edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have these file names in an array. You could do something like this.

```js
const arr = ["1. Some file name.txt", "2. Some file name.txt", "11. Some file name.pdf", "10. Some file name.txt", "1. Some file name.txt", "2. Some file name.txt", "2. Some file name.txt"];

const newArr = arr.map((item, index) => {
  const splited = item.split(".");
  splited.splice(0, 1); // remove the prefix
  return `${index + 1}. ${splited.join(".")}`;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: this also looks useful...will have to attempt this tomorrow. Many thanks.